# JAVA - Marshalling/Unmarshalling XML - duplicate element getting created during marshalling

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I was trying to marshal and unmarshall a XML. For simplicity i'm removing any annotations for namespaces.

Below is the structure of the XML which i'm finally looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RootElement>
  <Parent1>
    <Parent1Child1>
      <Parent1Child1Child1>v1</Parent1Child1Child1>
      <Parent1Child1Child2>v2</Parent1Child1Child2>
      <Parent1Child1Child3>v3</Parent1Child1Child3>
    </Parent1Child1>
    <Parent1Child2>v4</Parent1Child2>
  </Parent1>
</RootElement>
```

i've the RootElement class as below:

```
package com.mysoftkey.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

//@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement",namespace="http://yyyy")
@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement")
public class RootElement {
    //@XmlElementWrapper(name="Parent1",namespace="http://hhhh")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Parent1")
    @XmlElement(name="Parent1Child1")
    private ArrayList<Parent1Child1> p1;

    private String Parent1Child2;

    public void setparent1child1(ArrayList<Parent1Child1> Parent1) {
        this.p1=Parent1;
    }

    public ArrayList<Parent1Child1> getparent1child1(){
        return p1;
    }

    public String getparent1child2() {
        return Parent1Child2;
    }

    public void setparent1child2(String Parent1Child2) {
        this.Parent1Child2=Parent1Child2;
    }

    public void addparent1child1(Parent1Child1 Parent1Child1) {
        try {
                if (p1==null) {
                    p1=new ArrayList<Parent1Child1>();
                }
                p1.add(Parent1Child1);
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

i've the 'Parent1Child1' class as below:

```
package com.mysoftkey.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Parent1Child1")
public class Parent1Child1 {

    private String Parent1Child1Child1;
    private String Parent1Child1Child2;
    private String Parent1Child1Child3;

    public String getparent1child1child1() {
        return Parent1Child1Child1;
    }

    public void setparent1child1child1(String Parent1Child1Child1) {
        this.Parent1Child1Child1=Parent1Child1Child1;
    }

    public String getparent1child1child2() {
        return Parent1Child1Child2;
    }

    public void setparent1child1child2(String Parent1Child1Child2) {
        this.Parent1Child1Child2=Parent1Child1Child2;
    }

    public String getparent1child1child3() {
        return Parent1Child1Child3;
    }

    public void setparent1child1child3(String Parent1Child1Child3) {
        this.Parent1Child1Child3=Parent1Child1Child3;
    }
}
```

i've the main class for marshalling/unmarshalling as below:

```
package com.mysoftkey.jaxb;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class ParseXML1 {

    public static String xml_filepath="C:\\...\\Testxml2.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Create Parent1Child1 object and populate some values
        Parent1Child1 pcd1=new Parent1Child1();

        pcd1.setparent1child1child1("value1");
        pcd1.setparent1child1child2("value2");
        pcd1.setparent1child1child3("value3");

        RootElement rt1=new RootElement();
        rt1.addparent1child1(pcd1);
        rt1.setparent1child2("value4");

        //Initiate marshaller class
        JAXBContext cont=JAXBContext.newInstance(RootElement.class);
        Marshaller m=cont.createMarshaller();

        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(rt1, System.out);
        m.marshal(rt1, new File("C:\\...\\Testxml3.xml"));

        //Create JAXB context and initiate unmarshaller



        Unmarshaller um=cont.createUnmarshaller();

        RootElement root1=(RootElement)um.unmarshal(new FileReader("C:\\...\\Testxml3.xml"));
        ArrayList<Parent1Child1> pc1=root1.getparent1child1();
        //System.out.println(pc1.size());
        for (Parent1Child1 p:pc1)
        {
            System.out.println(p.getparent1child1child1());
            System.out.println(p.getparent1child1child2());
            System.out.println(p.getparent1child1child3());
        }
        System.out.println(root1.getparent1child2());
    }

}
```

when I execute the above i'm getting the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RootElement>
    <Parent1>
        <Parent1Child1>
            <parent1child1child1>value1</parent1child1child1>
            <parent1child1child2>value2</parent1child1child2>
            <parent1child1child3>value3</parent1child1child3>
        </Parent1Child1>
    </Parent1>
    <parent1child1>
        <parent1child1child1>value1</parent1child1child1>
        <parent1child1child2>value2</parent1child1child2>
        <parent1child1child3>value3</parent1child1child3>
    </parent1child1>
    <parent1child2>value4</parent1child2>
</RootElement>
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

Can someone please let me know why the 'Parent1Child1' tag is getting repeated twice. Once inside the 'Parent1' wrapper and again outside it.

If i comment the below section of the 'RootElement' class i'm getting the 'parent1child1' tag only once. Shouldn't I be annotating the 'parent1child1' as an XMLElement? Please help in understanding.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="Parent1")
@XmlElement(name="parent1child1")
```

output after commenting the above lines in the 'RootElement' class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RootElement>
    <parent1child1>
        <parent1child1child1>value1</parent1child1child1>
        <parent1child1child2>value2</parent1child1child2>
        <parent1child1child3>value3</parent1child1child3>
    </parent1child1>
    <parent1child2>value4</parent1child2>
</RootElement>
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to harmonize field and getter/setter names.

Comment: @lexicore, sorry, am not sure i'm completely getting it. could you please elaborate on what you mean by harmonize. did you mean that the xml fields and the getter/setter names should be the same?

Comment: Names of fields, getters and setters in your classes do not seem to follow the usual convention. Like `p1` vs. `setparent1child1` vs. `getparent1child1`. I am not sure that this is the cause but this might make JAXB think these are two different properties so they get marshalled twice - once via field (where annotations on the field are considered) and once via property (no annotations - default marshalling).

Comment: @lexicore. Thank you very much for the explanation and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lexicore is right. Notice the `<Parent1Child1>` (inside the Parent1 wrapper) and `<parent1child1>`. The `<parent1child1>` is generated from your getter/setters.

An easy way to get your desired xml while making the least changes in your code is to annotate your RootElement class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`. Using this, getter/setter pairs are bound to XML only when they are explicitly annotated by some of the JAXB annotations.

So your RootElement class would look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RootElement")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RootElement {
    //@XmlElementWrapper(name="Parent1",namespace="http://hhhh")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Parent1")
    @XmlElement(name="Parent1Child1")
    private ArrayList<Parent1Child1> p1;

    private String Parent1Child2;

    public void setparent1child1(ArrayList<Parent1Child1> Parent1) {
        this.p1=Parent1;
    }

    public ArrayList<Parent1Child1> getparent1child1(){
        return p1;
    }

    public String getparent1child2() {
        return Parent1Child2;
    }

    public void setparent1child2(String Parent1Child2) {
        this.Parent1Child2=Parent1Child2;
    }

    public void addparent1child1(Parent1Child1 Parent1Child1) {
        try {
            if (p1==null) {
                p1=new ArrayList<Parent1Child1>();
            }
            p1.add(Parent1Child1);
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

This I tried and it works. Changing the getter/setters to the usual conventions I think still would not work because your `<Parent1Child1>` starts with capital 'P' (haven't try it tho).